# How to suppress initialization warnings

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to suppress initialization due to coding conventions? For example line 17 has an initialization warning.

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<String> EntryText;
        ArrayAdapter<String> listviewAdapter;
        View rootView;

        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Sunshine Exception(onCreateView)", Integer.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()), e);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an error, not a warning.

Comment: And what would it return if `inflater.inflate` threw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to null explicitly so the compiler knows you know what you're doing.

```
View rootView = null;
```

This will at least get rid of your error.

Comment: So there's no @suppressWarnings() that you know of?

Comment: There's no way to suppress compiler errors; read: This is not a warning.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a warning, it will produce an error during compile time because you are trying to read local variable `rootView` but it could end up without a value if `inflater.inflate` throws an Exception